# Text to speech for multiple activities

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an application for workout with multiple activities that has text to speech for instructions.

My problem is that the text to speech takes too long to initialize even though i have it in a helper class and the instruction don't play when the activity starts, i thought maybe i should make a text to speech service, but i don't know how and i didn't find any tutorials.

```
private TextToSpeech mTts = null;
private boolean isLoaded = false;

public void init(Context context) {
    try {
        mTts = new TextToSpeech(context, onInitListener);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private final TextToSpeech.OnInitListener onInitListener = new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            mTts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
            isLoaded = true;
        }
    }
};


public void initQueue(String text) {
    if (isLoaded) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mTts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
        } else {

            mTts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    }
    else
        Log.e("error", "TTS Not Initialized");
}
```

How i can create a speech service and make it speak instructions from an activity?